# Handling complex formulas with := (data.table assignment by reference)

Tags: r, data.table

To calculate some aggregates of `x` over `label` and add it to data I could use following code, for `mean` it is :

```
library(data.table)  
setDT(data)[, y := mean(x), label]
```

but how to calculate means only when size of group given by `label` is over 5 and input 0 otherwise. I was first trying to calculate size of groups using `length`,`nrow` instead of `mean` keyword, but it is not the right way and doesn't work. Sample dataset I work with :

```
set.seed(123)

data<-data.frame(label=sample(c("A","B"),10,replace=TRUE),x=rnorm(10))
data
#   label          x
#1      A  1.7150650
#2      B  0.4609162
#3      A -1.2650612
#4      B -0.6868529
#5      B -0.4456620
#6      A  1.2240818
#7      B  0.3598138
#8      B  0.4007715
#9      B  0.1106827
#10     A -0.5558411
```

I see that trying code like :

```
setDT(data)[, y := ifelse(nrow(x)>10,mean(x),0), label] # don't run
```

is wrong direction.

Comment: In the example, the group size is A=4 and B=6.  So, I guess you need a condition of >4?

Comment: Are you looking for `setDT(data)[, indx := .N, label][, y := ifelse(indx > 5 ,mean(x), 0), label]`?

Comment: @akrun right, edition following

Comment: Try `setDT(data)[,  x:=if(.N>4) mean(x) else 0, label][]`

Comment: @yes this is the answer

Comment: are those solutions differ for very large datasets (a few millions of records) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest you avoid `ifesle` all together both because efficiency and because it's just wrong to put `0` when you don't want to calculate the mean, what will happen if one of the groups also will have a zero mean, how would you distinguish between them? I'd just do

```
setDT(data)[, y := mean(x)[.N > 4] , label][]
#     label          x          y
#  1:     A  1.7150650         NA
#  2:     B  0.4609162 0.03327823
#  3:     A -1.2650612         NA
#  4:     B -0.6868529 0.03327823
#  5:     B -0.4456620 0.03327823
#  6:     A  1.2240818         NA
#  7:     B  0.3598138 0.03327823
#  8:     B  0.4007715 0.03327823
#  9:     B  0.1106827 0.03327823
# 10:     A -0.5558411         NA
```

Comment: first time I hear about `if` being inefficient - please elaborate; fyi same NA's can be achieved using `setDT(data)[, y := if(.N > 4) mean(x), label]`

Comment: @eddi, OK I didn't test the `if` statement, though `ifelse` is for sure inefficient. Though I think that `if` and `else` combination could be inefficient.

Comment: ok, yes, I agree that `ifelse` is inefficient because it make unnecessary copies; re `if` + `else` - I doubt it - don't forget that you'll need to compare it to something that produces the same result

Comment: @eddie, Though my main concern is that people for some reason tend to believe that `0` is not a number and tend to use it instead of missing values.

Comment: @David Arenburg in reality I need to place some other constant instead of 0, it will be default value for very small subgroups

Comment: Then I guess akruns solution would be best. Though you could also do `setDT(data)[, y := 0][, y := mean(x)[.N > 4], label]` and avoid using `if` or `ifelse`. Though not sure what would be the fastest solution.

Comment: your solution in comment was first and it fits all demands of my question @David Arenburg

Comment: @DavidArenburg I did some benchmarks.  Looks like there is not much difference in speed between all the methods

Answer (score 5):

You could try

```
  setDT(data)[, y:=if(.N>4) mean(x) else 0, label][]
```

#### Benchmarks

Tried using `as.data.table` and `setDT` on "1e7" dataset with two groups for "label".  All the methods showed similar efficiency (though this might change when the number of groups increase)

```
set.seed(198)
data <- data.frame(label=sample(LETTERS[1:2], 1e7, replace=TRUE), x=rnorm(1e7))
data1 <- copy(data)
data2 <- copy(data)
data3 <- copy(data)
n <- 5e6
David1 <- function() {setDT(data)[, y := mean(x)[.N > n] , label]}
David2 <- function() {setDT(data1)[, y := 0][, y := mean(x)[.N > n], label]}
akrun <- function() {setDT(data2)[, y:=if(.N>n) mean(x) else 0, label]}
MrFlick <- function() {setDT(data3)[, y := ifelse(length(x)>n,
                           mean(x),0), label]}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(David1(), David2(), akrun(), MrFlick(),
                      unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
#     expr       min       lq      mean   median        uq       max neval cld
# David1() 0.9226054 1.005485 0.9975527 1.006531 0.9897817 0.9738954    20  ab
# David2() 1.0722181 1.058603 1.0388910 1.060785 1.0449793 0.9334972    20   b
#  akrun() 0.9843013 1.000373 0.9899616 1.001635 0.9917036 0.9492853    20  a 
#MrFlick() 1.0000000 1.000000 1.0000000 1.000000 1.0000000 1.0000000    20  ab
```

Changing `setDT` to `as.data.table`

```
 microbenchmark(David1(), David2(), akrun(), MrFlick(), 
              unit='relative', times=20L)
 #Unit: relative
 #     expr       min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 # David1() 0.9963619 1.0014244 0.9973844 1.006967 1.010804 1.015443    20  a 
 # David2() 1.1682075 1.1817214 1.1982023 1.185832 1.280648 1.176238    20   b
 #  akrun() 0.9885094 0.9986409 1.0085403 1.002375 1.004836 1.007429    20  a 
 #MrFlick() 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    20  a
```

Answer (score 2):

In this example, `x` is a vector so `nrow()` is the wrong function to use to see how many elements there are. Use `length`

```
set.seed(123)
data<-data.frame(label=sample(c("A","B"),10,replace=TRUE),x=rnorm(10))
setDT(data)[, y := ifelse(length(x)>4,mean(x),0), label]
data
#     label          x          y
#  1:     A  1.7150650 0.00000000
#  2:     B  0.4609162 0.03327823
#  3:     A -1.2650612 0.00000000
#  4:     B -0.6868529 0.03327823
#  5:     B -0.4456620 0.03327823
#  6:     A  1.2240818 0.00000000
#  7:     B  0.3598138 0.03327823
#  8:     B  0.4007715 0.03327823
#  9:     B  0.1106827 0.03327823
# 10:     A -0.5558411 0.00000000
```